# Jira recover user and password

Tags: jira, hsqldb

Hi I installed JIRA on a ubuntu box, but I forgot to write down my user/password (I know :/).

Mails are not working because the mail server isn't configured, and I can't access the admin panel.

The DB is a hsqldb db and I only have command line which seems impossible to run query's against.

How can I recover my user/password ?

Comment: also, the jiradb file is nowhere to be found. although it is configured in dbconfig.xml, the file seems to be a ghost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the HSQL Database Manager by shutting down JIRA, then running the following command:

```
java -cp /path/to/WEB-INF/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.5.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager \  
     -user sa \
     -url jdbc:hsqldb:/path/to/jira-home/database
```

...depending on the actual filename of the HSQL jar. The actual JDBC string should be available in JIRA admin somewhere.

This will then allow you to look in the `cwd_user` table for the user and reset the password as described here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Retrieving+the+JIRA+Administrator

You'll be able to see the users with this:

```
select u.user_name, d.directory_name 
from cwd_user u inner join cwd_directory d on u.directory_id = d.id 
order by directory_name, user_name;
```

Then reset the password like this:

```
update cwd_user 
set credential='uQieO/1CGMUIXXftw3ynrsaYLShI+GTcPS4LdUGWbIusFvHPfUzD7CZvms6yMMvA8I7FViHVEqr6Mj4pCLKAFQ==' 
where user_name='some-user-name'; 
-- new password is 'sphere'
```

**More details on HSQL Database Manager & Atlassian products:**

- [How to access the HSQL Database Manager during Atlassian Confluence add-on development](https://davidsimpson.me/2013/12/11/how-to-access-the-hsql-database-manager-during-atlassian-confluence-add-on-development/)
- [Accessing HSQL Database Manager](http://blog.networkedcollaboration.com/2012/03/15/accessing-hsql-database-manager/)